# How to use Office displayDialogAsync with oauth libraries

Tags: office-js

We implemented Office js Helpers for authentication in office Excel add-in. But due to refresh token features had to migrate other OAUTH libraries for below reason.

1) To support On-premise server 
2) To achieve refresh token/silent token

Hence we tried to replace Office js Helpers with one of OAUTH libraries using oidc-client using displaydialogasync but it got message "jsonMessage" and not getting any token hence kindly confirm about the implementation.

**auth.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">        
        <!-- Office JavaScript API -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>    
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.debug.js"></script>          
    </head>    
<body>  
</body>
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js"></script> -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.debug.js"></script>
<script src="/dist/auth.js"></script>
<script>
  Office.initialize = function () {
    showLogin();
    // Office.context.ui.messageParent("jsonMessage");
    console.log('first')
  };

</script>
</html>
```

**auth.ts**

```
import { User, UserManager, UserManagerSettings } from 'oidc-client';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

export { User };

export class AuthService {

  userManager: UserManager;
  constructor() {
    const settings = {
      authority: "https://qa-xxxxxxxx.com/xxxx/",
      client_id: "https://qa-xxxxxxxx.com/xxxx/",
      redirect_uri: "https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html",
      // silent_redirect_uri: `${environment.clientRoot}assets/silent-callback.html`,
      // post_logout_redirect_uri: `${environment.clientRoot}`,
      response_type: 'id_token token',
      scope: "openid read:investments read:profiles read:portfolios"
    };
    this.userManager = new UserManager(settings);
  }

  public getUser(): Promise<User> {
    return this.userManager.getUser();
  }

  public login(): Promise<void> {
    return this.userManager.signinRedirect();
  }

  public renewToken(): Promise<User> {
    return this.userManager.signinSilent();
  }

  public logout(): Promise<void> {
    return this.userManager.signoutRedirect();
  }
}
```

**taskpane.ts**

```
 if (localStorage.getItem('accessToken') == null) {
    if (OfficeHelpers.Authenticator.isAuthDialog())
      return;
    var dialog: any;
    var url: any;
    url = environment.AuthUrl;
    let loginDialog: Office.Dialog;

    const loginpopup =  function () {
       Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(
        url,
        {height: 40, width: 30},
        (result) => {
            if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                // displayError(`${result.error.code} ${result.error.message}`);
            }
            else {
                loginDialog = result.value;
                loginDialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, processLoginMessage);
                // loginDialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogEventReceived, processLoginDialogEvent);
            }
        }
    );

 function processLoginMessage(arg: any) {
        if (arg != "jsonMessage") {
          $(".loader").show();
          var test = JSON.parse(arg.message).value.split("#")[1].split("&")[1].split("=");
          let accessToken = test[1];
          localStorage.setItem('accessToken', accessToken);
          OfficeRuntime.storage.setItem('accessCustomToken', accessToken)
            .then((result) => {
              console.log(result);
            }, (error) => {
              console.log('Store error: ');
              console.log(error);
            });       
          loadProfiles();
          $('#lstPrfId').show();
          $("#lblprf").show();
          dialog.close();
        };
      }
```

@Rick... please find below updated changes and auth.html file getting opened without any errors but our identity server not getting opened on same which were configured in auth.ts file.

**New Files :**

**auth.html**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <!-- Office JavaScript API -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>    

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js"></script>

        <!-- For more information on Office UI Fabric, visit https://developer.microsoft.com/fabric. -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-core/9.6.1/css/fabric.min.css"/>

        <!-- Template styles -->
        <link href="taskpane.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


    </head>

<body>
    <title>OAUTH</title>
  <main id="app-body" class="ms-welcome__main" style="display: none;">
    <h2 class="ms-font-xl"> Discover what Office Add-ins can do for you today! </h2>
    <ul class="ms-List ms-welcome__features">
      <p class="ms-font-l">You Have been LoggedOut.</p>
</body>

<script src="/dist/auth.js"></script>
<script>
  Office.initialize = function () {

    // Office.context.ui.messageParent("jsonMessage");
    console.log('first')
    // Office.context.ui.messageParent( JSON.stringify({ status: 'success', result : user }) );
  };

</script>
</html>
```

**auth.ts**

```
import { User, UserManager, UserManagerSettings } from 'oidc-client';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

export { User };

Office.initialize = () => {

 class AuthService {

  userManager: UserManager;
  constructor() {
    const settings = {
      authority: "https://qa-xxxxxxx.com/oauth2/v1",
      client_id: "https://qa-xxxxxxxx.com/",
      redirect_uri: "https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html",
      // silent_redirect_uri: `${environment.clientRoot}assets/silent-callback.html`,
      // post_logout_redirect_uri: `${environment.clientRoot}`,
      response_type: 'id_token token',
      scope: "openid read:investments read:profiles read:portfolios"
    };
    this.userManager = new UserManager(settings);
  }

  getUser();

public getUser():Promise<any>{
  return this.userManager.getUser().then((user) => {
    if (user && user.access_token) {
      // return this._callApi(user.access_token);
      return Office.context.ui.messageParent( JSON.stringify({ status: 'success', result : user }) );
    } else if (user) {
      // return this.userManager.renewToken().then((user: User) => {
      //   return this._callApi(user.access_token);
      // });
    } else {
      throw new Error('user is not logged in');
    }
  });
}

  public login(): Promise<void> {
    return this.userManager.signinRedirect();
  }

  public renewToken(): Promise<User> {
    return this.userManager.signinSilent();
  }

  public logout(): Promise<void> {
    return this.userManager.signoutRedirect();
  }
}
};
```

**Blank Screen auth.html**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't know anything about `oidc-client` itself, but you can find some general guidance about using the Office Dialog API with OAuth libraries at [Auth with the Dialog API](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/develop/auth-with-office-dialog-api).
2. Office Helpers has built-in support only for Azure AD, Google, Facebook, Dropbox, and Microsoft Account. Since you are using your own auth server, you need to modify the helpers to add your custom endpoint. (See for example the helpers file endpoint.manager.ts.) But this would be a pointless complication. I really advise you to just not use the helpers at all.
3. I can't tell from your code what the value of `environment.AuthUrl` is, so I can't tell what URL you are passing to `displayDialogAsync`. I assume that it is auth.html. If it is not, then things are messed up.
4. It looks like you are loading auth.js with auth.html, but auth.ts only defines things. Then auth.html calls `showLogin` but that method is not in any of the libraries that you load with auth.html.
5. It looks like you are loading office.js twice in auth.html.
6. You've set the redirect URL to taskpane.html. I don't know how oidc-client` works, but that's almost certainly wrong. If the auth code is running in auth.html, then you want auth.html to be the redirect URL.

Comment: @Rick..Thanks for the reply. PFB my comments.  3)  environment.AuthUrl  set to auth.html only. 4) Since auth.js file builded under dist folder hence trying to reference the same.

Comment: @Rick...I have updated with latest code changes in main request... kindly confirm the same..

Comment: I have updated latest code and can you please review and confirm...

Comment: Address #6. Also, you declare a bunch of APIs in auth.ts, but it doesn't look like they are ever called.

Comment: it is referred auth.js file in auth.html on which it would be called....the same logical mentioned in this reference also                                     https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-OfficeAddins/blob/master/Samples/auth/Office-Add-in-Microsoft-Graph-React/login/login.html                                                                        "<script type="text/javascript" src="../login.js"></script>"

Comment: Can you provide your thoughts.?

Comment: Loading the auth.js file is not the same as calling the methods that are defined in the file. From the code that you have provided, it doesn't appear that you ever call the methods that you define.

Comment: it is called  getUser(); once configuration parameter set.